# how to reformat a json file in java

Tags: java, json, gson

Okay so this is my code -->
first we have a normal class:

```
public class Fencers{
    private String name,nation;
    private int id;

    public Fencers(String name, String nation,int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nation = nation;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                id+" "+name+" "+nation+"\n";
    }
}
```

then this is my main class trying to convert every class object to a json file using GSON

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Fencers fencer1 = new Fencers("m","egy",100);
        Fencers fencer2 = new Fencers("342","egy",120);
        String json = new Gson().toJson(fencer1);
        json += new Gson().toJson(fencer2);
        System.out.println(json);
     
    }
}
```

the only problem here is it prints `json` like this:

```
{
  "name":"m",
  "nation":"egy",
  "id":100
}
{"name":"342",
  "nation":"egy",
  "id":120
}
```

and I want them to be like this

```
[
 {
  "name":"m",
  "nation":"egy",
   "id":100
  },
  {
   "name":"342",
   "nation":"egy",
   "id":120
 }
]
```

really appreciate the help

Comment: You should create a list of `Fencers` and serialize that, instead of serializing individual objects and concatenating them.

Comment: Surely you need to put your objects in a collection and convert that to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Fencers fencer1 = new Fencers("m","egy",100);
        Fencers fencer2 = new Fencers("342","egy",120);
        List<Fencers> fencerList = new ArrayList<>();
        fencerList.add(fencer1);
        fencerList.add(fencer2);
        String json = new Gson().toJson(fencerList);
        System.out.println(json);
     
    }
```

Comment: Also, for pretty printing `new Gson()` has to be replaced with `new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect the elements in a collection (or just array).

```
Fencers fencer1 = new Fencers("m","egy",100);
Fencers fencer2 = new Fencers("342","egy",120);
List<Fencers> list = Arrays.asList(fencer1, fencer2);
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
System.out.println(json);
```